# Dual boot windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.1 on separate hard drives

Tags: ubuntu, partition, windows, dual-boot, ssd-hdd-hybrid

I have Asus N552VW with the firmwarre mode set to **Legacy** and the following disks:
* 128GB SSD: my windows 10 is installed on it
* 2 TB HDD partitioned exactly into two partitions

Knowing that, in the firmware, I have set the boot priority to:
[image: Firmware settings]

My question becomes: *Which device should I use for the **boot loader**?*
[image: Ubuntu installation]

Comment: So? Everything hunky-dory?  **:-)**

Answer (score 3):

The Boot Loader *goes onto your boot device* and as the boot device is your first drive: `/dev/sda`) that is where the Linux Boot Loader¹ should go.

In your particular firmware, disks are labelled my their disk brand names and as a Liteon is an SSD, that's where the existing OS gets booted from.

In Linux, disks are named `/dev/XdY` where `X` can be `h` or `s` depending on their controller and `Y` is a sequential number or letter respectively.

In your particular case `/dev/sda` and `dev/sbd` are your disks and `dev/sda1` is the first partition on the first disk, `/dev/sda2` the second partition on your first disk, `/dev/sdb1` the first partition on your second disk, etc...

<sub>**Note¹:** It's called GRUB2 of GRUB for Grand Unified Bootloader.</sub>

Comment: How can I know which device is my boot device?

Comment: That's an https://superuser.com question and off-topic here and on AskUbuntu  as that has nothing to do with neither Ubuntu, nor Unix and Linux: it depends on your firmware...

Comment: But this way, the boot loader is on one drive and the Ubuntu is on another drive. Is it OK?

Comment: I would not tell you to do anything dangerous without warning you. Above is the best I can do with the information I have.  If you have more information to divulge, please edit your original question, and then leave a comment here that you did.  I might update my answer or delete it depending on the edit.

Comment: I edited the question and added more info. what info do you need exactly?